# AJAX variable refresh help

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Im trying to find a way of refreshing a PHP variable on a webpage without reloading the entire page again, I just want the echoed variable to update at a set rate. Any help would be appretiated.

```
echo "Speed: " . ($APIkbpersec) . " KB/s";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to have that function in a seperate file and use an AJAX request to update it.
The standard is jQuery so I will show a very basic example of usage.

http://jquery.com/

```
<div id="Update">This will be updated</div>

$("#Update").load('YourUpdateScript.php');
```

This will request the php script and place the contents into the div named "Update".

To get it updating regulaly you need to have a timer set up:

```
// This is run when the document is ready, you could also run setInterval elsewhere if needed
$(document).ready(function (e) {

   setInterval ( RunUpdate, 3000 ); // Run once every 3 seconds

});

function RunUpdate() {
   $("#Update").load('YourUpdateScript.php');
}
```

A page refresh or calling clearInterval() will stop it from running.

Comment: `setInterval(RunUpdate(),3000)` should be `setInterval(RunUpdate,3000)`.  I fixed it for you.

Comment: Maybe you should explain how to get the actual data, by echoing the variable, or using XML/JSON etc.

Comment: here is my code: $url = "http://" . $host . ":" . $port . "/api?mode=queue&start=START&limit=LIMIT&output=json" . "&apikey=" . $APIKey;
$ctx = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('timeout' => 3)));
$urlContents = file_get_contents($url, 0, $ctx);
$APIArray = json_decode($urlContents, true);
$APIqueue = $APIArray['queue'];
$APIkbpersec = $APIqueue['kbpersec'];
$APIslots = $APIqueue['slots'];

Comment: That does not help, So long as your "YourUpdateScript.php" (Or what ever you name it) has stuff in it, it will return it. You need to use jQuery to get the contents dynamically :)